# input text in datatable row expansion returning null value primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I'm showing my database's data in datatable. In the row expansion, I'm setting some values and saving them to the database. I have an input text in row expansion, when I submit the the form the input text's value returning **null** in my backing bean.

```
<h:form id="form_2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <p:panel>
                             <p:dataTable var="questions" value="#{EVMView.loadQuestions(EVMView.strSO)}" id="mydatatable2" rowExpandMode="single" editable="true"> 
                             <p:ajax event="rowToggle" rendered="answerText" update="answertype_menu" listener="#{EVMView.onRowToggle(questions.question_ID)}"/>
                                <p:column style="width:2rem">
                                    <p:rowToggler/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Question">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{questions.questions}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:rowExpansion>
                                    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="panelmain">
                                    <p:outputLabel for="answertype_menu" value="Answer Type : "/>
                                    <p:selectOneMenu id="answertype_menu" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" value="#{EVMView.selectedOption}" required="true" requiredMessage="Select Sales-Order" height="333">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{EVMView.options(EVMView.selectedModule)}" var="values" itemLabel="#{values.evmOption}" itemValue="#{values.evmOption}"/>
                                        <p:ajax event="change" update="answerText" listener="#{EVMView.getAnswers}" rendered="answerText"/>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                    <p:outputLabel for="answerText" value="Answer:"  />
                                    <p:inputText id="answerText" value="#{EVMView.answer}" style="width:400px;" readonly="#{EVMView.readOnlyText}"/>
                                    
                                
                                        
                                            <p:outputLabel for="param1" value="#{EVMView.param1Name}" rendered="#{EVMView.visibleParam1}"/>
                                            <p:inputText id="param1" value="#{EVMView.param1}" rendered="#{EVMView.visibleParam1}"/>
                                        
                                        
                                            <p:outputLabel for="param2" value="#{EVMView.param2Name}" rendered="#{EVMView.visibleParam2}"/>
                                            <p:inputText id="param2" value="#{EVMView.param2}" rendered="#{EVMView.visibleParam2}"/>
                                        
                                        
                                            <p:outputLabel for="param3" value="#{EVMView.param3Name}" rendered="#{EVMView.visibleParam3}"/>
                                            <p:inputText id="param3" value="#{EVMView.param3}" rendered="#{EVMView.visibleParam3}"/>
                                        
                                
                                    
                                    
                                            
                                                <p:fileUpload listener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
                                                multiple="true" sizeLimit="1000000" fileLimit="3"
                                                allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>
                                            
                                    
                                    <p:commandButton value="Save EVM Record" action="#{EVMView.saveRecord}" process="@this" update="growl"/>
                                    </p:panelGrid>
                                </p:rowExpansion>
                             </p:dataTable>
                </p:panel>
            </h:form>
```

A part of my backing bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="EVMView")
@ViewScoped
public class EVMView {
    @EJB
    private PublicService publicService;
    @EJB
    private EVMService evmService;
    
    private EVMQuestions evmQuestions=new EVMQuestions();
    
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{loginBean}")
    LoginBean loginBean;
    
    private String strSO;
    private List<SalesOrder> salesOrders;
    private List<String> allModules;
    private List<String> allHeaders;
    private List<EVMQuestions> allQuestions;
    private String selectedOption;
    private List<EVMOptions> optionList;
    private String answer;
    private String selectedModule;
    private String receivedAnswer;
    private int questionID;
    private boolean readOnlyText=true;
    private String param1Name;
    private boolean visibleParam1=false;
    private String param1;
    private String param2Name;
    private String param2;
    private boolean visibleParam2=false;
    private String param3Name;
    private String param3;
    private boolean visibleParam3=false;
    private String mySessionUsername;
    private String mySessionFTEC;
    private String savedDate;
    private EVMResponses evmResponses;
    private EVMParameters evmParameters;
    private String engineType;
    private String selectedHeader;
    

    public String getParam3Name() {
        return param3Name;
    }
    public void setParam3Name(String param3Name) {
        this.param3Name = param3Name;
    }
    public String getParam3() {
        return param3;
    }
    public void setParam3(String param3) {
        this.param3 = param3;
    }
    public boolean isVisibleParam3() {
        return visibleParam3;
    }
    public void setVisibleParam3(boolean visibleParam3) {
        this.visibleParam3 = visibleParam3;
    }
    public boolean isVisibleParam2() {
        return visibleParam2;
    }
    public void setVisibleParam2(boolean visibleParam2) {
        this.visibleParam2 = visibleParam2;
    }
    public String getParam2Name() {
        return param2Name;
    }
    public void setParam2Name(String param2Name) {
        this.param2Name = param2Name;
    }
    public String getParam2() {
        return param2;
    }
    public void setParam2(String param2) {
        this.param2 = param2;
    }
    public String getParam1Name() {
        return param1Name;
    }
    public void setParam1Name(String param1Name) {
        this.param1Name = param1Name;
    }
    public boolean isVisibleParam1() {
        return visibleParam1;
    }
    public void setVisibleParam1(boolean visibleParam1) {
        this.visibleParam1 = visibleParam1;
    }
    public String getParam1() {
        return param1;
    }
    public void setParam1(String param1) {
        this.param1 = param1;
    }
    public boolean isReadOnlyText() {
        return readOnlyText;
    }
    public void setReadOnlyText(boolean readOnlyText) {
        this.readOnlyText = readOnlyText;
    }
    public int getQuestionID() {
        return questionID;
    }
    public void setQuestionID(int questionID) {
        this.questionID = questionID;
    }
    public String getReceivedAnswer() {
        return receivedAnswer;
    }
    public void setReceivedAnswer(String receivedAnswer) {
        this.receivedAnswer = receivedAnswer;
    }
    public List<String> getAllHeaders() {
        return allHeaders;
    }
    public void setAllHeaders(List<String> allHeaders) {
        this.allHeaders = allHeaders;
    }
    public String getSelectedModule() {
        return selectedModule;
    }
    public void setSelectedModule(String selectedModule) {
        this.selectedModule = selectedModule;
    }
    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }
public void saveRecord()
{
    System.out.println(this.param1);
}
```

I couldn't understand why I'm getting **null**.

Comment: @JasperdeVries Yes, thanks. I updated the process attribute to this **process="@this param1 param2 param3 answerText"**

Comment: You probably want something like `process="@(.myClass :input)"`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58693156/880619

Comment: @JasperdeVries I have one more question, when I click file upload button the filename comes **null**. How can I solve it on this situation?